# Getting html Email Content in JavaMail

Tags: java, android, html, jakarta-mail, content-type

I've made an E- Mail Client for my Android- Phone using the JavaMail API. I dont knoq how to get the E- Mail Content if it's a html- Mail. I'm using the following Code to get the Content:

```
public void printMessage(int messageNo) throws Exception {
    Log.i("MsgNo", "Getting message number: " + messageNo);

    Message m = null;

    try {
        m = folder.getMessage(messageNo);
        dumpPart(m);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException iex) {
        Log.i("Out of Range","Message number out of range");
    }
}

public static void dumpPart(Part p) throws Exception {

    if (p instanceof Message)
        dumpEnvelope((Message)p);
    Object content = p.getContent();
    Log.i("dumpPart",(String) content);
    String ct = p.getContentType();
    try {
        pr("CONTENT-TYPE: " + (new ContentType(ct)).toString());
        Log.i("MsgNo", "Content Type");
    } catch (ParseException pex) {
        pr("BAD CONTENT-TYPE: " + ct);
        Log.i("MsgNo", "Bad Content Type");

    }


     //* Using isMimeType to determine the content type avoids
   //  * fetching the actual content data until we need it.

    if (p.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
        pr("This is plain text");
        pr("---------------------------");
        Log.i("Text", (String)p.getContent());       
    } else {
         Log.i("MsgNo", "Just a Separator");
        // just a separator
        pr("---------------------------");

    }
}
```

In the Logcat, i get the return value of dumpenvelope((Message)p); , but after that nothing.

Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is any exception thrown?

Did you [enable debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and examine the protocol trace to see what might have failed?

Are you using IMAP?

It looks like your program was created out of pieces of the JavaMail sample program called msgshow.java, did you find the complete original sample program?

[This JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody) might help as well.

Comment: No, ther's no exception thrown, and if I use the sample program msgshow, i get every return value until "This is plain text ---------------------", but (String)p.getContent() returns nothing. For test, i made after (String)p.getContent() a simple Log.i call, but I dont get this in LogCat, so I think (String)p.getContent() is the Problem. I'm using POP3, do I have to use Imap?

Comment: The protocol trace would be helpful to debug this.  With POP3 you have to wait for the entire message to download before accessing any of the content.  If the message is large, that might take a long time.  You might try setting a timeout in case something is going wrong when talking to the server.  And, unless you have a strong reason not to use IMAP, I would suggest using IMAP instead.

Comment: Okay, now I'm using IMAP, but I dont get the Message content. If I try the possibility with MimeMessage wich you can find in every forum, I only get Data- rubbish from the funktion  as content...

Comment: What does the protocol trace show, and what does your code look like currently?  Have you tried wrapping everything in a try/catch(Exception) to make sure no unexpected exceptions are being thrown?

Comment: Ok, I made a mistake, there's an Exception thrown but I didn't saw It. If I run the dumpPart Methode from the msgshow demo File in my Application, I get this Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.util.QPDecoderStream cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: That means there's something wrong with the JAF (javax.activation) configuration.  Probably it's an Android-specific problem.  If you search here, you'll probably find workarounds.