# Message Content to String Exception

Tags: android, string, email, jakarta-mail

I'mworking on an E- Mail Client for my Android Phone using the JavaMail API. If I try to get the Content of an E- Mail, I get the following text in the logCat:

> FROM: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>
> TO: AG Blasorchester
>
> SUBJECT: BITTE DENKT AN DIE SCHWARZE MAPPE / RINGORDNER
>
> SendDate: Wed Feb 27 21:30:49 MEZ 2013
>
> CONTENT-TYPE: TEXT/PLAIN; charset=iso-8859-1
>
> Message Content:
>
> Fehler: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.sun.mail.util.QPDecoderStream cannot be cast to java.lang.String

This is the thrown exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.util.QPDecoderStream cannot be cast to java.lang.String

I use the following code to get the Content:

```
public static void dumpPart(Part p) throws Exception {
    Log.i("Gestartet", "dumpPart Gestartet");
    if (p instanceof Message)
        dumpEnvelope((Message)p);

    /** Dump input stream .. 

    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    // If "is" is not already buffered, wrap a BufferedInputStream
    // around it.
    if (!(is instanceof BufferedInputStream))
        is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    int c;
    while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
        System.out.write(c);

    **/

    String ct = p.getContentType();
    try {
        pr("CONTENT-TYPE: " + (new ContentType(ct)).toString());
    } catch (ParseException pex) {
        pr("BAD CONTENT-TYPE: " + ct);
    }
    String filename = p.getFileName();
    if (filename != null)
        pr("FILENAME: " + filename);

    /*
     * Using isMimeType to determine the content type avoids
     * fetching the actual content data until we need it.
     */
    try{
    if (p.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
        pr("This is plain text");
        pr("---------------------------");
        if (!showStructure && !saveAttachments)
        System.out.println((String)p.getContent());
    } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
        pr("This is a Multipart");
        pr("---------------------------");
        Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
        level++;
        int count = mp.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        dumpPart(mp.getBodyPart(i));
        level--;
    } else if (p.isMimeType("message/rfc822")) {
        pr("This is a Nested Message");
        pr("---------------------------");
        level++;
        dumpPart((Part)p.getContent());
        level--;
    } else {
        if (!showStructure && !saveAttachments) {
        /*
         * If we actually want to see the data, and it's not a
         * MIME type we know, fetch it and check its Java type.
         */
        Object o = p.getContent();
        if (o instanceof String) {
            pr("This is a string");
            pr("---------------------------");
            System.out.println((String)o);
        } else if (o instanceof InputStream) {
            pr("This is just an input stream");
            pr("---------------------------");
            InputStream is = (InputStream)o;
            int c;
            while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
            System.out.write(c);
        } else {
            pr("This is an unknown type");
            pr("---------------------------");
            pr(o.toString());
        }
        } else {
        // just a separator
        pr("---------------------------");
        }

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("Fehler", "Fehler: " + e);
    }
}
```

Can I get the Message Content as a String without an exception?

Comment: Don't know that API, but my guess is that         System.out.println((String)p.getContent());
  p.getContent isn't returning a string, its returning a decoder and you need to get the data from it.  Your other cast to string looks ok.

Comment: Yes, I think so too, but if I use System.out.println((String)p.getContent().toString()), I get the same Error, and I dont know why. In every JavaMail Tutorial or in a demo program is used the same code and it seems to run. Why not in my application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting html Email Content in JavaMail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987472/getting-html-email-content-in-javamail)

Comment: Yes, but know In that thread I asked for the fail, now I want to know the reason and a solution for it, because I didnt found one in the Internet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are there any German special characters in the From: XXXX-part in you sample or anywhere else in the headers? The email is RFC 2047 encoded, which happens when email headers contain [non-US ASCII](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html) characters.

This code might work. Completely untested as I haven't got the environment set up, but might be a starting point.

```
if (p.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
  pr("This is plain text");
  pr("---------------------------");
  if (!showStructure && !saveAttachments) {
    if (p.getContent instanceof String) { 
      System.out.println((String)p.getContent());
    } else if (p.getContent() instanceof QPDecoderStream) {
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(p.getContent());
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      while (true) {
        int c = bis.read();
        if (c == -1) {
          break;
        }
        baos.write(c);
      }
      System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray()));
    } else {
       //Handle different content types
    }
  }
}
```